# ZF1 is calling unexpected controller

Tags: zend-framework

I have controller named

> AbcController

, which is in default module. So it's normally called like

> ```
> somedomain.com/abc
> ```

..and everything is dispatched correctly, however in case uf URL

> somedomain.com/!abc

OR

> somedomain.com/@abc

iŧ's still routed to

> AbcController

, question is why ? Or better question is, where exactly is the url param transformed to controller name ? I'm trying to find that few hours by debugger.

**Expected behavior: controller not found exception**

**Current behavior: view !abc/inde.phtml not found**

This is completely strange, please point me. Thank you.

**Update:**

So, after more time I found the reason, why any characters such ! and @ are trimmed:

```
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract::_formatName()
```

function is doing following:

```
 $segment        = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '', $segment);
```

Question is, how to skip that and to get correct state (not existing controller)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there isn't clear solution, or at least I didn't find any. Actually I have workaround - using static router to some other action, like "ind" instead of "index". In case of bad character, controller will be matched, but default action not, what will result in requested 404 response.

Issue is in ZF1 itself, as controller names are claned, but action names aren't. Shoulld be both or nothing, I think.